# Can I use AWS S3 with Google Speech-to-Text in larger files?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-speech

I tried to use Google Cloud Speech-to-Text in my node.js project. It works fine with smaller files that I've on my disk but I wanted to get longer files that are stored in AWS S3. Is it possible or I need to use Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1):

You can use google cloud storage libraries in your node.js code to access AWS s30 storage:

"The Cloud Storage XML API is interoperable with some cloud storage tools and libraries that work with services such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) and Eucalyptus Systems, Inc. To use these tools and libraries, change the request endpoint (URI) that the tool or library uses so it points to the Cloud Storage URI (https://storage.googleapis.com), and configure the tool or library to use your Cloud Storage HMAC keys." [For more information please check Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability)

Comment: It seems to me that S3 is supported in terms of a "migration" to Google Cloud i.e. the file must be first migrated to GCloud, then they can be used: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating

Answer (score 1):

For longer audio files, you can only use files in Google Cloud Storage. You can't use audio files stored in AWS S3. https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionAudio

Comment: This is correct. See my comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57906335/758836